# How i can update extjs framework version in Sencha Architect for my application?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I wanted to update the framework version in my application to 6.7.0. I tried a lot, downloaded the new version of Sencha Architect, used the commands from the documentation. As a result, the framework seems to have been updated, but it has not been updated either.

In the console after entering the command "Ext.getVersion()", I see that the current version of the framework is 6.7.0.

[image]

In Sencha Architect worth version 6.6.0.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the .xds file manually.
Apparently there is no way to upgrade from previous versions to ExtJS 6.7 in Architect itself.

The manual process is described on 
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?471559-Architect-4-2-5-framework-upgrade&p=1324163&viewfull=1#post1324163

But beware and back up, it could break your project: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?471572-Architect-4-2-5-breaks-interactions-of-type-rotate-on-piecharts